# Energy dissipated by friction and entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, friction, dissipation

Can we compute the entropy increase in some simple dissipative systems?

Imagine a block sliding on a frictional floor and that its initial kinetic energy is $K$, let's imagine that the ambient temperature is $T$. It would be correct to assume that the entropy increase of the universe after the block has stopped is:

$$\Delta S = \frac{K}{T}$$

1. If so, could we present a more detailed calculation of how this entropy would increase?
2. Would it be appropriate to use the mathematical relation $\partial S/\partial U = 1/T$ and, therefore, assume that $\dot{S} = -\dot{K}/T$?

Comment: Why would ambient temperature be relevant? In the entropy increase formula $dS \geq dQ/T$, the relevant temperature is that of the block, at its surface where conversion of kinetic energy into internal energy happens.

Comment: @JánLalinský you are right the only restriction is $\Delta S > K/T$.

Comment: @Davius I am considering posting an answer, but need some clarifications.  1. What is the "ambient" in your description? Is it the surrounding air? The floor? Something else? 2. Are you looking for the change in entropy in the final equilibrium state, or immediately after the block stops which is before equilibrium is reached.

Comment: @BobD 1. Possibly the floor is much more important than the surrounding air, but feel free to make any additional assumptions. 2. I was thinking about the entropy increase just as the block stops.

Comment: Determining the entropy change before equilibrium is reached is problematic as one normally computes entropy change between equilibrium states. So I guess I'll take a pass on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If the initial temperature and the final temperature of the block are both T, then applying the complete version of the first law of thermodynamics to the block gives $Q=-K$, where Q is the amount of heat transferred to the block from the surroundings (the room air), a negative eqantity.  Assuming that the thermal inertia of the block is negligible compared to the room air, the final temperature of the block and its final internal energy U will be essentially the same as in the initial state.  So the change in entropy of the block will be negligible.

The room air can be regarded as an ideal constant temperature reservoir, which has received the quantity of heat $Q_{res}=-Q=K$.  For an ideal (essentially) constant temperature reservoir, the entropy change is Q/T.  So the change in entropy of the room air is $\Delta S_{air}=K/T$.  This is also the change in entropy of the universe.

Comment: The block transfers some part of the heat into the floor, which would also get hotter than $T$. $K/T$ is more of an upper bound on the entropy produced, valid if floor and air layers in contact with the block stayed at temperature $T$ at all times. This could be realistic for an ice floor at 273.15 K, where the point of phase transition ice-liquid would maintain the temperature constant, but normal solid floor would heat up in the layer that is in contact with the block.

Comment: @JánLalinský  It was my assumption that the floor and walls of the room were thermally insulated.  I suspect that this was the OP's intention (for simplicity).  If the floor were ice, the room air would be losing heat to the floor during the process, and this would have to be accounted for.

Comment: It seems we read the question differently. I assume the friction process releases major part of the generated heat into the floor, since the work is done irreversibly at the interface between the block and the floor, not between the air and the block.

Comment: @JánLalinský Well, if the floor is assumed insulated, the heat first enters the block and then flows into the air.

Comment: Floor is insulated from what, the block? Why would that be the case?

Comment: @JánLalinský The floor is assumed to be made of insulation material.  Its thermal conductivity is assumed zero.  Do you have a problem with that idealization?

Comment: Only that I don't see the question implying it, otherwise I don't have a problem with it, it is one possible model.

Comment: So in your model, only the block gets hot and releases heat into the air, and the floor is not getting any heat? That is quite an idealization of the real process. I prefer to consider the more realistic case where both air and the floor get some heat.

Comment: @ChetMiller Hi Chet. Are you looking at this from the perspective of entropy increase after the block and air reach thermal equilibrium or sometime before that. The reason I ask is I'm curious why you said the thermal inertia of the block is negligible compared to the air instead of saying the heat capacity of the block is negligible compared to the air.

Comment: @bobd. After reaching equilibrium.  By thermal inertia, I mean heat capacity.

Comment: Thanks Chet for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

> It would be correct to assume that the entropy increase of the universe after the block has stopped is:
>
> $$\Delta S = \frac{K}{T}$$

This would be correct only provided the temperature of the "frictional floor" would stay $T$ at all times. Then the floor would eventually accept heat $K$ at temperature $T$, so the standard entropy relation $\Delta S = \Delta Q/T$ would apply.

However, in reality the block surface would get hot due to friction, and in the common scenarios temperature of the block surface $T_B$ would be higher than the ambient temperature $T$. This would heat up the floor surface in contact with the block, so its temperature $T_F$ at any time would be dependent on position, but always higher or equal to $T$ and lower than $T_B$. Hypothetically, there could be a floor material that could get much hotter than $T$ at the leaving edge of the block, and this would make net entropy produced of the order $K/T_F$ much smaller than $K/T$. The higher the temperature achieved on the floor surface due to friction, the smaller the entropy produced would be. Somewhat curiously, the entropy produced is maximized when the friction is very small and the motion takes a lot of time, so the floor does not increase its temperature. Conversely, strong friction means quick deceleration to rest, high floor temperatures and thus low entropy production.

Right after the block stops, entropy generation will continue, because there is some non-equilibrium distribution of temperature in the block and the floor which evolves towards new equilibrium state with new temperature $T'$. If the floor has large heat capacity, then $T' = T$ and it seems likely that in this final equilibrium state, total entropy produced will be $\geq K/T$.

Comment: "This would be correct only provided the temperature of the "frictional floor" would stay  at all times".  Could you elaborate on why the floor needs to be considered a thermal reservoir? Why not the air? Or both?

Comment: @BobD the irreversible work and thus energy release happens at the interface block - floor. So internal energy of both block and floor increases immediately. Heat transfer to the air may happen too if the air is present, but it happens later, both from the block to the air and from the floor to the air.

Comment: But it’s “later” we are interested in when internal thermal equilibrium is achieved. So no matter where the local temperature increases initially occur  between the block and the floor,  eventually the block, floor, and air will all be in equilibrium with whatever reservoirs there are. The total entropy increase will be K/T, I.e., the entropy generated by the irreversible friction work

Comment: @BobD the original question is about entropy produced "after the block has stopped". You may interpret this as entropy produced in the limit $t\to\infty$. I understood it as entropy produced at the time the block reaches zero speed.

Comment: @BobD And I am not sure that for $t\to\infty$ the answer is certainly $K/T$. Maybe when additional assumptions are adopted, such as infinite heat capacity of the floor+air, and non-existence of other entropy generation processes (no wear and tear of the floor and the block).

Comment: Jan, to me, when the OP says  the "ambient temperature is $T$" it implies that the ambient air is a thermal reservoir. If that is the case, then any local temperature increase of the block and floor due to friction work will eventually result in heat transfer from the block/ floor to the ambient air with the end result the increase in entropy will be K/T. But that's just my opinion, FWIW. Bob

Comment: The ambient temperature may also mean temperature of the floor, which I assumed in my answer. In a real process, both air and the floor would absorb some of the energy released, and I agree that if the final temperature is still $T$, then $K/T$ is a possible answer, but I would not reject $>K/T$ either, since the process is irreversible work, not a reversible heat transfer.

Comment: It is the irreversible work $K$ that resulted in the heat $Q$ transferred to the reservoir, i.e., $Q=K$. As such I can't see how, once equilibrium is reached, that $\Delta S\gt K/T$.  The amount of heat transferred to the reservoir can't be greater than the friction work $K$ that created it.

Comment: How exactly the irreversible work is done matters. If it is done very slowly, very low friction, the floor and the block do not degrade, and the final state is as you say, total entropy generated is $K/T$. But the faster the process, the higher the friction force and the bigger the wear and tear in the block or the floor. This increases the generated entropy.

Comment: I am assuming, as is customarily done in kinetic friction problems, that the kinetic friction force is a constant, i.e.,. independent of the speed of the sliding object, which is generally considered the case for low speeds. So let's assume for our model that that is in fact the case.

Comment: Yes that is a common model of friction. I think we have resolved everything, no need to discuss this more.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for exchanging thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be correct to assume that the entropy increase of the
> universe after the block has stopped is:
>
> $$\Delta S = \frac{K}{T}$$

In response to my query, you indicated that the "ambient temperature $T$" is the floor and that by "after the block has stopped", you mean immediately after it stops.

The equation $\Delta S=\frac{K}{T}$ presupposes that all the heat $Q$ generated by the friction work, which equals the loss of kinetic energy of the block $K$, is transferred to a thermal reservoir of constant temperature $T$, which you have designated to be the floor (but could just as well be the air).

This would be true after thermal equilibrium is reached but not immediately after the block stops at which point $\Delta S\lt\frac{K}{T}$. In order for $\Delta S=\frac{K}{T}$ immediately after the block stops,  heat transfer from the block to the floor would have to occur instantaneously, that is, the thermal conductivity of the block would need to be infinite.

Hope this help